# adding variable using if statement

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file containing trainee names and a csv file containing a list of publications, including a variable defining the author's name. I'd like for R to add a variable to the publications dataframe containing a dummy variable if the author name in the publication matches any of the trainee names ("peeps") contained in the trainee file.  The following code isn't working for me, and I can't figure out why.  The error I receive is "object 'i' not found.  Am I going about this all wrong?  Thanks!

```
publications <- read.csv("publications.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
trainees <- read.csv("TraineeRoster.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

peeps <- trainee$LastName

publications["TraineePub"]
for (i in 1:nrow(publications)) {
    if (publications$AuthorLast[i] == peeps) {
        publications$TraineePub[i]
    } else {
        publications$TraineePub[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ifelse`?  It may work better here than a `for` loop and an `if-else` statement

Comment: I haven't tried that.  I'm pretty new to r.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. Since your example is not reproducible (see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [**here**](http://www.sscce.org/), and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)), I made up some data.

```
set.seed(123)
publications <- data.frame(AuthorLast = sample(letters[1:10]), TraineePub = "no")
peeps <- letters[1:5]

publications$TraineePub[publications$AuthorLast %in% peeps] <- "yes"
publications

#    AuthorLast TraineePub
# 1           c        yes
# 2           h         no
# 3           d        yes
# 4           g         no
# 5           f         no
# 6           a        yes
# 7           j         no
# 8           i         no
# 9           b        yes
# 10          e        yes
```

Comment: Thanks @Henrik, this helps tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look through some R tutorials, as your code doesn't do anything apart from reading the original tables.  The code should look like this.

```
publications <- read.csv("publications.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
trainees <- read.csv("TraineeRoster.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
peeps <- trainee$LastName

publications$IsTrainee = 1*(publications$AuthorLast %in% peeps & publications$AuthorFirst %in% trainee$FirstName)

write.csv(publications,file='PublicationsTrainee.csv')
```

A few things wrong with the code above, though:

`publications["TraineePub"]` doesn't do anything.  You can add commas to try to reference rows or columns named "TraineePub", but I don't know if that variable even exists.

`publications$TraineePub[i]` calls a value, but it doesn't do anything with it (unless you call `print`, which will print the value.

Edit:  Also, you should try to avoid using `for` loops as much as you can.  Learn to use `apply` or just vector operations (e.g. `c(1,2,3,4,5)+c(2,0,3,1,3)` is equivalent to `c(3,2,6,5,8)`)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I can't believe I've made it through 2 MOOCs and O'Reilly's R Cookbook, and I'm still running into basic stumbling blocks like this.  Your feedback really helps.  Thank you! @user1362215